# Upsides of reporting a lower or upper bound vs. reporting the actual value

Tags: reporting

I often see research papers reporting lower or upper bounds. [E.g.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=1544953):

> Patients treated with the splint regained mobility significantly more quickly (**p less than 0.001**) and preferred the splint to the plaster cast. The range of dorsiflexion at the ankle improved more rapidly after treatment in the splint (**p less than 0.001**), and patients were able to return to normal activities sooner.

What are the advantages of doing so instead of reporting the actual value (rounded if necessary)?

Comment: As a psychologist, I half-suspect it's because psychologists don't want to count 0s and don't remember that scientific notation exists.

Comment: @Kodiologist :)

Comment: See also [Is the exact value of a 'p-value' meaningless?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/94974/17230).